# Facebook publish_permission is returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to request for `publish_actions` from my users after logging in with Facebook. The logging in is successfull but `publish_actions` window won't even pop up. 
I have tried the below code to get user permissions to `publish_actions` to user's wall but it keeps returning error.

```
function autoPost(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        console.log("Response 1", response);
        FB.api('/me/permissions/publish_actions', function(response) {
            console.log("Response 2", response);
            if ((response.data[0].status === "granted")){
                publish = 1;
            }
            else {
                publish = 0;
            }
        });
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions', return_scopes: true});
}
```

Response 1 returns **Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}**

Response 2 returns **Object {data: Array[0]}**

And the **ERROR** itself is **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change anything in your code. Just need to visit your facebook application page and submit the review **publish_actions** , after you are approved everything should work fine.

Comment: This is the problem and it actually solved it for me.

Comment: But I have an issue with the permission to use here: **1**. Lets people post to Facebook using a custom composer
**2**. Publishes Open Graph stories
**3**. Publishes content to Facebook automatically
**4**. Lets people publish to Facebook using the Share dialog or Feed dialog
Which is the right option for my case? I chose 3 and it says **Apps won't be approved for this use of publish_actions. To be approved, apps must follow our review criteria and the guidelines for using publish_actions.**

Comment: I think the way your apps work is not approved. You can change the way it work to meet the review criteria first. And maybe upgrade the code later :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don´t need to use another API call to get the permissions if you already use `return_scopes`. The authorized permissions will be in the response of `FB.login` already.

That being said, if you don´t get asked for `publish_actions` in the authorization process, it´s most likely because you are trying with a user without a role in the App. `publish_actions` needs to get reviewed by Facebook before you can go public with it.

The error is obvious, there is no "response.data[0]". It´s not a good idea to access array values directly with their index. The array may not be filled, as it´s the case here.

More information about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review